# how to update the drawing area with new scatter points?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, scatter-plot

I have wrote a program that connects to a GPS receiver and pulls out coordinates from it. I would like to create a scatted plot on which i am going to plot the location points pulled from the receiver, this plot should be updated each time a new observation is available. 
her is my serial port reader class, it allows me to pulls data from the receiver:

```
class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {         
            try {
                String tmp = SP.readString();
                String[] msgs = tmp.split("\r\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < msgs.length; j++){
                    if (msgs[j].contains("$GPGGA") && msgs[j].length() > 60){
                        System.out.println(msgs[j]);
                        NMEA nmea = new NMEA();
                        nmea.parse(msgs[j]);
                        System.out.println(nmea.position.toString());
                        writer.write(nmea.position.toString() + "\n");
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (SerialPortException ex) {System.out.println(ex);} 
            catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex);}
        }
    }
}
```

here is my port connector method:

```
public void openport(){
    try {   
        SP.openPort();
        SP.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        SP.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader(),SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);

        String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String file = dir+"\\NMEAout\\nmeaClean.txt";
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        Canvas C = new Canvas();
        C.setBackground(Color.green);
        frame = new JFrame("canvas");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(500, 500);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.add(C);
    } 
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {System.out.println(ex);} 
    catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex);}
}
```

and here is my Canvas class which should allow me to plot the points on screen. it is not finished, this is the part which i need help in:

```
class Canvas extends JPanel{
    int x = 100, y = 100;
    public void newParam (int xnew, int ynew){
        x = xnew;
        y = ynew;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 5, 5);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

`frame` is a `JFrame` object declared at the top of my main class.
the problem is that i do not understand how to get the Canvas plot new points after i obtain them through the event listener. i would also like to plot the new points without deleting the old ones.

can anyone help? any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem is that i do not understand how to get the Canvas plot new points after i obtain them through the event listener

You need an API in your custom painting class that allows you to add new points to be painted.

There are then two common approaches for doing incremental painting:

1. Keep a List of Points to draw and then iterate through the List each time and draw the point
2. Draw each point onto a BufferedImage and then just paint the BufferedImage.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both of these approaches. Try both to see which you prefer better.

Comment: you mean i need a method that will store the new location into the x and y?  that method should be called from the serial event method?

Comment: @DanyLavrov, no that is NOT what I mean. Every time you paint the component the old painting is erased and a new painting is done. So with your code you will only ever have a single oval even if you change the x/y values.  Did you try the demo code from the link provided. It contains working examples that are similar to what you want. The code allows you to add additional Rectangles to be painted. You want an Oval. The code already has an `addRectangle(...)` method.  It should not be that hard to go from a Rectangle to an Oval.